# Wait on main thread with sleep in goroutine

Tags: go, sleep, channel

Wrote this very basic code to understand channels.

1. If there is a wait in a goroutine, why is the main goroutine waiting on it? I read that the main goroutine needs to have a wait time as the control is passed back to it immediately after invoking goroutine.
2. Why are goroutines not designed like main thread and child threads in java where they can run in parallel?

```
func main() {
    channel := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(3*time.Second)
    }()

    for {
        fmt.Println("../");
        <-channel
    }
}
```

Comment: The main goroutine does not wait for the sleep to end, it will print `../` immediately. If you don't see it, chances are you have `GOMAXPROCS` set to 1, and so it's subject to goroutine scheduling. Goroutines run concurrently, and they may run parallel (it's not the same).

Comment: "Why are goroutines not designed..." you'd have to ask the designers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your main thread is waiting for something to come from the channel

```
func main() {
    channel := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(3*time.Second)
        channel <- 1 // Sending something to the channel to let the main thread continue
        channel <- 2
    }()

    for {
        fmt.Println("../");
        <-channel // Waiting for something to come from the channel
    }
}
```

regarding your specific questions:

> If there is a wait in a goroutine, why is the main goroutine waiting
>   on it?

It doesn't wait for it, it probably waiting on the channel.

> I read that the main goroutine needs to have a wait time as the
>   control is passed back to it immediately after invoking goroutine.

If your main wasn't waiting on the channel (or stack in an endless loop) it had finished and closed the application. GoRoutines closes with the main thread (like Java daemon threads)

> Why are goroutines not designed like main thread and child threads in
>   java where they can run in parallel?

They actually do (:

Comment: Alright, so this means that main thread and the goroutines can run in parallel. However, it seems like there is no default wait in a goroutine to wait on a channel to receive data.

Comment: No, there is no default wait in the GoRoutine. It's up to you to write/read to/from a channel both in the GoRoutine and in the main thread.

Comment: @agyeya - if it answerd your question, please approve.